# SQL-Server Scheduling Concurrency

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job

If I have several jobs all running from the same hourly schedule, do they run concurrently or in serial? These are all SSIS tasks that are independent. I'm running these jobs on a VM that is not very beefy.

This question is really directed at SQL Server 2014 & 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I have several jobs all running from the same hourly schedule, do they run concurrently or in serial?

SQL jobs run concurrently,the only exception for this is when schedules overlap,ie., job A runs every two hours,for some reason one day it keeps on running for more than 2 hours,in this case the next 2 hour schedule of job wont run

Answer (score 0):

They will all run in parallel. A lot of environments (2014) I work on do that - jobs run in parallel scheduled with equal frequencies.